# How can clearly show image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, imshow

I want show large image in Matlab gui, but when show my image not clearly and not possible for read. for example show my image in Matlab in follow.

[image: show my image in Matlab]

Any way show my image like this image?

[image: Image 2]

I know can use zoom in and zoom out, but image in first should clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InitialMagnification` to preview the image at your native resolution. If your concern is getting a nice looking zoomed-out image, you can try using `reduce` parameter of `imshow` to sub sample it.

Comment: What is InitialMagnification? How can use this function.

Comment: @FarzadNadi I think `imshow(AA,'InitialMagnification',100)` should work

Comment: in this way not work in axes. i want, show in the axes on gui . do you know how i do?

Comment: no work. only size of image is reduce. and same quality. not possible to read.